# Exclude iOS from running JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iphone, html

I'm using a preloader from an article, [QueryLoader2 – Preload your images with ease](http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/queryloader2-preload-your-images-with-ease/). Works great in most desktop browsers, but I'm having issues with it on iOS.

Is there a way to exclude iOS devices running the script without serving a different page?

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").queryLoader2({
        barColor: "#FFFFFF",
        backgroundColor: "#000000",
        percentage: true,
        barHeight: 1,
        completeAnimation: "grow",
        minimumTime: 1000
    });
});
```

I can't get the `window.addEventListener` to work with iOS for some reason.

Comment: Did you try the code on the part of that link pertaining to iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the user agent string.

```
if(!((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || 
   (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) ||
   (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)))) {
    // do non iOS stuff here
}
```

Your code will look like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(!((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || 
      (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) ||
      (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)))) {

        $("body").queryLoader2({
            barColor: "#FFFFFF",
            backgroundColor: "#000000",
            percentage: true,
            barHeight: 1,
            completeAnimation: "grow",
            minimumTime: 1000
        });
    }
});
```

I would also look into the iOS code provided on that page to see if that resolves your issue.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    $("body").queryLoader2();
});
```

Comment: This is the action that calls it 

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").queryLoader2({
        barColor: "#FFFFFF",
        backgroundColor: "#000000",
        percentage: true,
        barHeight: 1,
        completeAnimation: "grow",
        minimumTime: 1000
    });
});
Where do I dump that script?

(sorry im not great with javascript)

Comment: I can't get the window.addEventListener to work with iOS for some reason, it appears to be one or the other.

Your code works great for excluding iOS though!

Answer (score 1):

Check for the the Iphone user agent string and conditionally preload the images based on that result